# How do i hide description block if no data found

Tags: magento-1.9, blocks, custom-options, custom-block

I am using magento version 1.9 and I need to hide description block if no data found, if data exits the block shows description, if not found, that should be  hide.

Comment: Which magento version you are workingon?

Comment: magento : 1.9.2.3

Comment: find the file which returns the product description there you can write the condition to check empty field.

Answer (score 0):

Go to product view page

```
app/design/frontend/Your-namespace/Your-theme/template/catalog/product/view.phtml
```

Put your description block code between below condition:

```
if($_product->getDescription()){
  //description block goes here
}
```

Comment: make sure if data exits  the description will show

Comment: Yes it will show if description have data

Comment: pls check the path

Comment: app/code/ design

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/5iuJJKH.png

Comment: app/design/frontend/Your-namespace/Your-theme/template/catalog/product/view.phtml

Comment: @JeevaRathinam updated answer please check it

Answer (score 0):

The file can be found here:
`/app/design/frontend/[theme name]/[package name]/template/catalog/product/view/attribute.phtml`

Open the file and search for the following lines:

```
    <?php foreach ($_additional as $_data): ?>
<tr>
    <th class="label"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->__($_data['label'])) ?></th>
    <td class="data"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code']) ?></td>
</tr><?php endforeach; ?>
```

Replace the entire foreach loop with the following lines of code:

```
<?php foreach ($_additional as $_data): ?>
    <?php $_attribute = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute($_data['code']);
    if (!is_null($_product->getData($_attribute->getAttributeCode())) && ((string)$_attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($_product) != '')) { ?>
    <tr>
        <th class="label"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->__($_data['label'])) ?></th>
        <td class="data"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code']) ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>

<?php foreach ($_additional as $_data): ?>
    <?php $_attribute = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute($_data['code']);
    if (!is_null($_product->getData($_attribute->getAttributeCode())) && ((string)$_attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($_product) != '')) { ?>
    <tr>
        <th class="label"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->__($_data['label'])) ?></th>
        <td class="data"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code']) ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

You can find here:  [Hide attributes with no value](https://tejabhagavan.blogspot.in/2016/03/hide-magento-attributes-with-no-value-2.html)

Comment: this also for default description, right //

Comment: Yes, i think, there is one description

Comment: have you cleared this issue?